# Звідки взялася у вжитку форма “завдяки ним”?

Tags: вживання-слів, займенники

Чому кажуть “завдяки ним” замість “завдяки їм”? Є які-небудь історичні підстави для цього?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Це явище пов'язане з історичним розвитком займенника як частини мови. Вказівні за походженням займенники **онь, она, они** ще в спільнослов‘янській мові стали
виконувати роль особового займенника третьої особи ([Історична граматика](http://philology.lnu.edu.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/%D0%86%D0%93.-18-16.pdf)).
   Під час розвитку мови, при видмінюванні займенника **они** з'явився *протетичний н*, який згодом то зникав, то залишався.([ЕТАПИ СТАНОВЛЕННЯ ЗАЙМЕННИКА ЯК ЧАСТИНИ МОВИ Галій Л. Г.](http://www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe?I21DBN=LINK&P21DBN=UJRN&Z21ID=&S21REF=10&S21CNR=20&S21STN=1&S21FMT=ASP_meta&C21COM=S&2_S21P03=FILA=&2_S21STR=Sdzif_2010_8_16))

**Ї** з'явилося набагато пізніше у нашій мові, так і  відповідно **їм**. В деяких діалектах української мови залишилися впливи староукраїнської, як наслідок цього - бачимо вживання **ним** у  названих конструкціях.